# Slide listView Row onClick

Tags: android, listview, slidetoggle

I have a listView, populated with an ArrayList of object (xml parsing) and an adapter.
I would like to do this : 

When clicking on a row, the full description slide toggle to be fully display.

Don't know how to do it..

http://christopherbrookes.fr/STACK.png

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your correctly than this should be exactly what you are looking for http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html